# Keep reducing values in a list until all of them are 0

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, while-loop

I have an initial list called `origin_list`. I want to pick a position in this list at random and reduce the value of that positional element by 1 until all of them are 0. What would the fastest way to do this be?

I have some rather inaccurate pseudo-code below to get an idea of what I'm trying to do

```
import numpy as np
origin_list = [120,240,201]
while all(origin_list)>=0:
    rand_int = np.random.randint(0,len(origin_list))
    origin_list[rand_int] = origin_list[rand_int]-1
    if origin_list[rand_int]==0:
    # Continue with reducing only the non-zero elements in the list
```

Comment: I don't know why you need to do that. Anyway, what do you mean by `Remove rand_int position from the list`? If you are removing the value after it's 0 then your break condition for while loop will be when length of list is 0.

Comment: Since you aren't doing anything inside the loop, the *quickest* way is to skip to the end of the loop and set everything to 0.

Comment: @Mark I want to do other things in the loop. I'm thinking that this is one way of going about what I want to do.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh I just edited my question. If one value reaches zero, I want to keep reducing the others to zero.

Comment: Are you even going to use the modified `origin_list` in your loop? If it just determines how many iterations you'll have in the end, it's as simple as `for _ in range(sum(origin_list)): # do stuff`

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, I am going to be using it in my loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need Numpy here — since you explicitly want to loop over values it doesn't add much. You could just take a list of indices of your list and use the random module to choose one. When that list reaches zero, remove the index. When the list of indices is empty stop:

```
import random

origin_list = [5,4,7]
positions = list(range(len(origin_list)))
                 
while positions:
    p = random.choice(positions)  
 
    # do something
    
    origin_list[p] -= 1 
    if origin_list[p] == 0:
        positions.remove(p)  

print(origin_list)
# [0, 0, 0]
```

The efficiency is probably going to depend mostly on the part `# do something`.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your *pseudo-code* to do your task.

```py
import numpy as np

origin_list = [120,240,201]
index_list = list(range(len(origin_list))) # For keeping track of all remaining indexes(for which origin_list is not 0)

while len(index_list) != 0:
    rand_int = np.random.randint(0,len(index_list))
    index = index_list[rand_int] # Choosing random index from remaining indexes where data is > 0
    
    origin_list[index] = origin_list[index]-1
    
    # Do your task here

    if origin_list[index]==0:
        index_list.pop(rand_int) # Removing that index from available list of indexes
```

I am basically just maintaining the available list of **indexes** where origin_list's value is greater than `0`.

Each index will be removed from the list where its related element in the **origin_list** reaches 0.